# How can I read the user from my custom @EnableACMEDatasource(user="foo")?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have dozens programs that connect to the same database using different credentials. I don't want the very same JDBC URL `jdbc:postgresql://pg.acme.com/myapp` to show up in dozens `application.properties` files, so I thought to introduce a `@EnableACMEDatasource` to be used in mupltiple applications like this:

```java
@EnableACMEDatasource(user="billing", pass="${billing.pass}")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Billing { /*...*/ }

@EnableACMEDatasource(user="payments", pass="${payments.pass}")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Payments { /*...*/ }

@EnableACMEDatasource(user="accountant", pass="${accountant.pass}")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Accuntant { /*...*/ }
```

The `@EnableACMEDataSource` annotation `@Import`s an `ACMEDataSourceAutoConfiguration` that defines beans of type `DataSource`, `DSLContext`, `TransactionManager` and so on. My problem is I don't know how to read user and password when I need them to instantiate beans:

```java
@Configuration
public class AcmeDataSourceAutoconfiguration {
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("acme")
  public DataSource acmeDataSource() {
    // HOW DO I READ "user" and "pass" from @EnableACMEDataSource?
  } 
}
```

I have an implementation based on a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` but the code is difficult to maintain and is not detected by Intellij, Checkstyle and so on, so lots of red warnings appear in static analysis tools at injection points.